# Transform values inside object of object

Tags: javascript, object, transformation

I would like to transform values inside an object of an object. Something like this:

Initial object:

```
const studentDetails = {
   'details1': {Name: "John", CountryName: "US", value: 1},
   'details2': {Name: "David", CountryName: "AUS", value: 2},
   'details3': {Name: "Bob", CountryName: "UK", value: 3},
};
```

Transformed object:

```
{
   'details1': {Name: "John", CountryName: "US", value: 2},
   'details2': {Name: "David", CountryName: "AUS", value: 3},
   'details3': {Name: "Bob", CountryName: "UK", value: 4},
};
```

I did something like this already but could not figure it out

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(studentDetails).map(([key,
value]) => [key, some data transformation on value]))
```

Comment: So you're just incrementing the value?

Comment: It could be any transformation on the value key so incrementing, squaring, dividing etc

Comment: If you don't care about mutating the object just loop over it and change the value. `for (const prop in studentDetails) { ++studentDetails[prop].value; }` or whatever the calculation is. Non-mutation is only slightly different, but you certainly don't need `Object.fromEntries` or `map` to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. We define a `transformValue` function which takes in the student details object and any transform function. Then applies the transform function on every value and returns the whole transformed details object.

```js
const studentDetails = {details1: { Name: "John", CountryName: "US", value: 1 }, details2: { Name: "David", CountryName: "AUS", value: 2 }, details3: { Name: "Bob", CountryName: "UK", value: 3 }};

const transformValue = (details, transform) => {
    return Object.entries(details).reduce((acc, [key, detail]) => {
        acc[key] = {
            ...detail,
            value: transform(detail.value)
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});
};

console.log(transformValue(studentDetails, (val) => val + 1)); // Increments value
console.log(transformValue(studentDetails, (val) => val * val)); // Squaring values
```

Comment: Watch out for [`reduce/spread`](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't involve `Object.fromEntries` or `reduce`. Just [iterate over the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement), adding updated objects to `output`, and then returning `output`.

```js
const data={details1:{Name:"John",CountryName:"US",value:1},details2:{Name:"David",CountryName:"AUS",value:2},details3:{Name:"Bob",CountryName:"UK",value:3}};

const increment = (n) => n + 1;
const decrement = (n) => n - 1;

function transform(data, prop, fn) {
  const output = {};
  for (const key in data) {
    output[key] = {
      ...data[key],
      [prop]: fn(data[key][prop])
    };
  }
  return output;
}

const update1 = transform(data, 'value', increment);
const update2 = transform(update1, 'value', decrement);

console.log(update1);
console.log(update2);
```